# I have found a bug--how do I know which to report to?

Tags: unity, launcher, gimp, bug-reporting, tuxguitar

I have found a bug with a few applications such as Gimp 2.8 and TuxGuitar on 12.04. Whenever I start the application, its icon will not appear on the Alt-Tab switcher and it will not appear on the Launcher. But, pinning the application to the launcher and then loading the program will allow the icon to be on the switcher.

Here is my question: Should I report this bug to Unity or to Gimp/TuxGuitar?

Comment: My opinion is Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens with multiple applications; the common factor is the Unity launcher. Therefore, as [aking1012](https://askubuntu.com/users/5768/aking1012) commented, you should report this against `unity` with `ubuntu-bug unity`. In the (somewhat unlikely) event that this turns out not to be the right package, it can be changed later (by you or a triager or developer).

Make sure your bug report thoroughly describes the problem, including what applications trigger it and which do not. Please also read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first (if you haven't done so already).